# Swift - app crashes on TableView UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When I start to update the table view (pull down to refresh), and then suddenly start flipping list, the application crashes.

> fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BankCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as BankTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 233/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let bank:Bank = self.allRates[indexPath.row] as Bank // <-- Error here

    cell.titleLabel.text = bank.name

    return cell
}
```

Probably I have to check the existence of an element in the array. But is this the right way out?

-
I edit row #2:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BankCell") as BankTableViewCell
```

But the error still remains.

My refresh function:

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{

    parser.deleteObjects()
    self.allRates.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    parser.parse { // - XMLParser ended to Parse file

        self.allRates = self.parser.actualBankRates + self.parser.notActualBankRates

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

In XMLParser:

```
var actualBankRates = [Bank]()
var notActualBankRates = [Bank]()
```

Comment: does it crash after pull down to refresh and reloading with updated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that your "allRates" array can be accessed at that index. Write the following code to make sure it won't crash:

```
if self.allRates.count > indexPath.row
{
    // Ensure you get a valid Bank returned
    if let bank = self.allRates[indexPath.row] as Bank
    {
        cell.titleLabel.text = bank.name
    }
}
```

You could then debug it by sticking a breakpoint on the first if statement and typing `po self.allRates` to check the state of your array before you tried accessing it.

Comment: Working, but what about else operator? I must return empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register your class and therefore `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is unable to return the cell, e.g. call

```
tableView.registerClass(BankCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BankCell")
```

when initializing your table view delegate.

*Edit* check, that your array `allRates` is initialized and filled. The error means, that it is empty.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - in cell.titleLabel.text = bank.name

Comment: On of those is an optional and `nil`. You have to check which.